# Error bars on single points in dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm using dygraphs to display data with errors. For theoretical data this is completely fine, since it also makes an "error band" around the line - great. However, experimental data is normally based on discrete measurements, adding this kind of data I would like to be able to display only the measured points with their respective error - not drawing error bands to the nearest available points.

I could add a `NaN` point on each side of the data points to make the error band invisible, however - as the name suggests - it is actually invisible, so even when hovering over the point I can't see the error.

Is there any way to implement error bars for single data points? Especially when mixed with errorbands enabled series?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyuzppky/) showing the case. Line A should be a normal line with errorband, line B only points with per-point errors.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [custom plotter](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/introducing-custom-plotters.html):

```js
function singleErrorPlotter(e) {
  var ctx = e.drawingContext;
  var points = e.points;
  var g = e.dygraph;
  var color = e.color;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle = e.color;

  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var p = points[i];
    var center_x = p.canvasx;
    if (isNaN(p.y_bottom)) continue;

    var low_y = g.toDomYCoord(p.yval_minus),
        high_y = g.toDomYCoord(p.yval_plus);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(center_x, low_y);
    ctx.lineTo(center_x, high_y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  ctx.restore();
}
```

Here's an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/fyuzppky/1/) of your fiddle which uses this.

Comment: Thank you, that looks great! Looking at your blog post, it should be possible to set this as a per series option - however, switching the plotter option to the line "B" seems to not work properly - line A has the proper, normal error band appearance, but the error bars on line A are again invisible.

Comment: I don't believe you can set a list of plotters per-series. Feel free to file a [feature request](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues) for it, though.

Comment: Hmm? Is this not exactly what you are doing at the end of your blog entry, combining a line chart with a custom bar chart?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't understand the `Dygraph.Plotters.linePlotter` line - removing this one for the per-series option brings the perfect result: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1nz8uq4m/). Thank you so much, dygraphs is awesome!